# Count distinct and unique values in pivot table or other way?

Tags: excel, excel-2021

I have a contract table, with amendment, type and stats columns. But the table source lists the contract and all amendments as a separate row.

I need to categorize contracts by their type and status, based only on the last stats, i mean, based on the highest amendment.

A pivot table return strange results.

My table sample:

```
contract    Type    amendment   stats 
contract 4  service 0   active
contract 1  rent    0   expired
contract 3  lending 2   expired
contract 1  rent    2   active
contract 1  rent    1   active
contract 3  lending 1   expired
contract 2  service 2   revoked
contract 4  service 1   active
contract 3  lending 0   expired
contract 2  service 0   expired
contract 3  lending 3   expired
contract 2  service 1   expired
contract 1  rent    3   expired
```

A pivot data counting distinct contracts:

[image]

And when i double clicked in services field:

[image]

A contract can't be 2 stats at same time, the last stats (based on highest amendment) is the unique valid to count. "Contract 2" is considered as "revoked" and expired in this pivot table.

How can I do this? I can't use the "remove duplicates" feature because can't delete any rows from the table.

---

Edit:

The expected output is:

[image]

In this image, each contract was counted only once in each type and stats.

It doesn't necessarily have to be a pivot table, if it's possible to do this using only formulas, that's also valid.

Comment: Can you clarify your expected results? Also, from the fact that you are using Distinct Count I take it that your table has been added to the Data Model?

Comment: @JosWoolley Added the expected output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can also be accomplished using Power Query, available in Windows Excel 2010+ and Microsoft 365 (Windows or Mac)

To use Power Query

- Select some cell in your Data Table
- `Data => Get&Transform => from Table/Range`
- When the PQ Editor opens: `Home => Advanced Editor`
- Make note of the Table **Name** in Line 2
- Paste the M Code below in place of what you see
- Change the Table name in line 2 back to what was generated originally.
- Read the comments and explore the `Applied Steps` to understand the algorithm

After running the Power Query

- Select `Close and Load To`

  - `PivotTable Report`
- Choose either a new sheet of existing worksheet and a cell
- Create your pivot table by dragging

  - `Type` to **Rows**
  - `Status` to **Columns**
  - `Status` to **Values** (should default to *Count*)

```
let

//Change next line to reflect data source
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{
        {"contract", type text}, {"Type", type text}, {"amendment", Int64.Type}, {"status", type text}}),

//Group by contract
//then filter each subgroup to extract the item with the latest amendment
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Changed Type", {"contract"}, {
        
//If the latest amendment will always refer only to a single item, Table.Distinct can be removed
       {"Latest", (t)=>Table.Distinct(Table.SelectRows(t, each [amendment] = List.Max(t[amendment]))), 
         type table [contract=nullable text, Type=nullable text, amendment=nullable number, status=nullable text]}}),


//Expand the appropriate columns in the table
    #"Expanded Latest" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Grouped Rows", "Latest", {"Type", "status"})
in
    #"Expanded Latest"
```

***Data***
[image]

***Results after Pivoting***
[image]

You could also do the entire process in Power Query, although adding the Row Totals and Column Totals is a bit more complex:

```
let

//Change next line to reflect data source
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{
        {"contract", type text}, {"Type", type text}, {"amendment", Int64.Type}, {"status", type text}}),

//Group by contract
//then filter each subgroup to extract the item with the latest amendment
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Changed Type", {"contract"}, {
        
//If the latest amendment will always refer only to a single item, Table.Distinct can be removed
       {"Latest", (t)=>Table.Distinct(Table.SelectRows(t, each [amendment] = List.Max(t[amendment]))), 
         type table [contract=nullable text, Type=nullable text, amendment=nullable number, status=nullable text]}}),


//Expand the appropriate columns in the table
    #"Expanded Latest" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Grouped Rows", "Latest", {"Type", "status"}),

//Pivot on Status and aggregate by Count
    #"Pivoted Column" = Table.Pivot(#"Expanded Latest", 
                            List.Distinct(#"Expanded Latest"[status]), "status", "contract", List.Count),

//Add total column and row
    #"Add Row Totals" = Table.AddColumn(#"Pivoted Column","Row Totals", 
        each List.Sum(List.RemoveFirstN(Record.FieldValues(_))), Int64.Type),

    #"Add Column Totals" = Table.InsertRows(
        #"Add Row Totals",
        Table.RowCount(#"Add Row Totals"),
        {Record.FromList({"Grand Total"} 
            & List.Accumulate(
                List.RemoveFirstN(Table.ColumnNames(#"Add Row Totals"),1),
                {}, 
                (s,c)=>s & {List.Sum(
                                Table.Column(#"Add Row Totals",c))}), Table.ColumnNames(#"Add Row Totals"))})
in
    #"Add Column Totals"
```

***Result from PQ alone***
[image]

Comment: If I need to add or update contracts data, will changes in the source table be reflected in the power query and pivot table? Or will I have to redo this process every time?

Comment: @BlastoiseOpressor Depends on what is updated. If you are adding contracts, or changing statuses, adding services, it should work OK. Remember though that things are case-sensitive in PQ. In other words, without adding some coding `Active` and `active` will be counted separately.

Comment: Just curious, how would you declare column name in the "type table..." row, when it is composite? E.g.: "contract number".

Comment: @BlastoiseOpressor `[contract number=text, #"ID/Serial" = text]`. Depends on the separator between the words. If it is just a space vs other characters. If you omit the `#" "` construct and it is needed, PQ will flag an error at that point.

Comment: Thanks! I made some changes for my real case and it worked as expected!